# ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs saved the file as "file" format and didn't save as pdf

Tags: vba, excel, save-as

At specific times this macro is enabled, however it saved the file as a format "file". The file itself changed its name and is open in excel though. Plus it didn't save as pdf. The destination is: C:\Users\User\Desktop\macro save

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Range("F6").Text, _
                      FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, _
                      CreateBackup:=False



ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                                Filename:=Range("f6").Text, _
                                FileFormat:=xlpdf, _
                                Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                                IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                                IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                                OpenAfterPublish:=False

End Sub
```

It worked fine before so I'm confused on what changed

Comment: The `FileFormat:=xlpdf, _` line does not belong.

Comment: thank you, that worked for pdf, is there any way to fix the excel save file issue?